# Trouble installing TIA portal: sqlcmd.exe is missing

Tags: plc, siemens, tia-portal

I'm trying to install Siemens TIA portal, but get a setup error.
The setup states that "Some installed products need licenses", but shouldn't it just work with a trial license? It does give some error related to the missing of sqlcmd.exe.
The specific version I have is: TIA Portal STEP 7 Professional V15.1.

Setup screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvl0a.jpg
Log file:

```
2019.09.25 10:22:38 - Year.Month.Day - Log start

BUNDLE: SIMATIC TIA Portal STEP 7 Professional V15.1 - WinCC Advanced V15.1
SEBU Version: Advanced:TIA.rgs.RTM_15010000:V15.01.00.00_28.01.00.01

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Professional, 64-bit, build 18362
COMMANDLINE: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Siemens\Automation\Siemens Installer Assistant\406\SIA2.exe /starter /bundlepath=F:\TIA\InstData
INSTALLDIR: D:\Tia simulation
SETUPLANGUAGE: 1033
PRODUCTLANGUAGES: 1033

CHANGES: (+)DotNet_Updater;(o)CONFSQL2014EXP;(+)SYMLINK;(+)SYMLINKADD;(+)NCMGPRS64;(+)NCMFWL64;(+)OPC;(+)SECON;(o)S7DOS64;(o)S7DOS;(+)S7EDB;(+)Automation Software Updater;(+)TIA_Portal;(+)MU_Client;(+)HWCN-HWCOL;(+)SUPBASEH02;(+)SUPBASEH03;(+)SUPBASEH04;(+)SUPBASETO01;(+)SUPBASETO02;(+)SUPBASEWCF01;(+)TIAP_SIMATIC;(+)TIAP_SIMATIC32;(+)STEP7;(+)WinCC Runtime Advanced Simulator;(+)PTSymLib;(+)PTTouchInput;(+)HM_AllEditions;(+)HM_NoBasic;(+)UMC64;(+)LicenseManager;(+)STOP_ALMSERVICE;(o)AlmPanelPlugin64;(o)Prosave;(+)TIA_ES;(+)TIA_ES32;(+)WinCC_Tr_Mandatory;(+)WinCC_TrC_All;(+)WinCC_TrC_CAP;(+)CoRtHmiRTmDriver64;(+)HMIRTMV11;(+)RT_Adv_Sim;(+)TIACOMPCHECK;(+)TIA_Opns;(+)TIAADMIN;(+)AWB_SOFT;(+)AWB_ALM;(+)AWB_TIAUMAC;(+)MUSERVER

There are NO severe messages before the installation


10:22:38 | BEGIN. Execution started.
10:22:44 | OK                        RunningProcesses           ()                          Complete
10:22:44 | OK                        InventoryBefore            (A)                         Complete
10:22:44 | OK                        Citamis                    (Before)                    Complete
10:23:12 | OK                        SecurityControlFeature     (ReturnFeatures)            Complete
10:23:12 | OK                        StartApplBefore            (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.OBJECTFRAME.FILESTORAGE.SERVER.EXE)Complete
10:23:12 | OK                        StartApplBefore            (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]X64\BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.OBJECTFRAME.FILESTORAGE.SERVER.EXE)Complete
10:23:12 | OK                        ClassicCompPrepare         ()                          Complete
10:23:12 | OK                        ProductRegistration        (Before)                    Complete
10:23:12 | OK                        ClassicCompAfterUninstall  ()                          Complete
10:23:12 | OK                        SetupUnit                  (DotNet_Updater)            Complete  Foreign   AddLocal  
10:23:12 | OK                        Checkpoint                 (E)                         Complete
10:23:14 |ERROR    AdsWorkerClassicProduct::OnWorkerCompleted():  - ClassicProduct setup result: -1: File path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe is missing
10:23:14 | FAIL!                     SetupUnit                  (CONFSQL2014EXP)            Failed    ClassicProductReinstall 
10:23:14 | FAIL!                     Checkpoint                 (E)                         Complete
10:23:14 |ERROR    ExecutionEngine::StartNextStepAsync():  - Execution has been cancelled. Probably because of some process(es) running on the machine
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SYMLINK)                   Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SYMLINKADD)                Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (NCMGPRS64)                 Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (NCMFWL64)                  Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPC)                       Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SECON)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7DOS64)                   Skip      ClassicComponentReinstall 
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7DOS)                     Skip      ClassicComponentReinstall 
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7EDB)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Automation Software Updater)Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Portal)                Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_Portal)                Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Portal)                Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (MU_Client)                 Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HWCN-HWCOL)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH02)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH03)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH04)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASETO01)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASETO02)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEWCF01)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAP_SIMATIC)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAP_SIMATIC32)            Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STEP7)                     Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC Runtime Advanced Simulator)Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (PTSymLib)                  Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (PTTouchInput)              Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HM_AllEditions)            Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HM_NoBasic)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (UMC64)                     Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (UMC64)                     Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (UMC64)                     Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (LicenseManager)            Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (LicenseManager)            Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (LicenseManager)            Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STOP_ALMSERVICE)           Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AlmPanelPlugin64)          Skip      ClassicComponentReinstall 
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Prosave)                   Skip      ClassicProductReinstall 
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_ES)                    Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_ES32)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_Tr_Mandatory)        Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_TrC_All)             Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_TrC_CAP)             Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (CoRtHmiRTmDriver64)        Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (HMIRTMV11)                 Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HMIRTMV11)                 Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (HMIRTMV11)                 Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (RT_Adv_Sim)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIACOMPCHECK)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Opns)                  Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_Opns)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Opns)                  Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAADMIN)                  Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_SOFT)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_ALM)                   Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_TIAUMAC)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (MUSERVER)                  Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     ClassicCompAfterInstall    ()                          Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     ClassicCompRollback        ()                          Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     HspInstall                 ()                          Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     MspInstall                 ()                          Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\INSTALLROOTCERTIFICATE.EXE)Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.GENERATOR.FRAMEWORK.EXE)Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\S7EPATSX.EXE)Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\S7EPAESX.EXE)Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.SIMATIC.HWCN.INTERPRETER.IG.GSD.GENERATOR.EXE)Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     ProductRegistration        (After)                     Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     InventoryAfter             (Z)                         Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     LicenseTransfer            (False)                     Skip
10:23:14 | SKIP!                     SetupReport                ()                          Skip
10:23:16 | OK                        SetupIsComplete            ()                          Complete
10:23:16 | OK                        Citamis                    (After)                     Complete
10:23:17 | OK                        SetupSummary               ()                          Complete
10:23:17 | END. Execution completed.

Intermediate ExitCode after execution queue : 1603 - Exit code means: Installation failed (InstallFailure)
Errors: 2
Warnings: 0
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by uninstalling Microsoft SQL server 2014, did this via the control panel. After that, I had to manually remove the Microsoft SQL server folder in `Program Files` and delete some registry keys.